# Mongodb query forward from username X

Tags: mongodb

I have problem whit long Mongo find results. Example how can i start query starting from `_id` X
to forward Example I know I have document where is 1000 users details I know there is user called Peter in list I can make query `Users.find({userName: "Peter"})` and get this on user `_id` but how I can get all users also after this with out I need return JSON from above "Peter"

Comment: Do you have your data sorted by any means?

Answer (score 2):

With the little amount of information you have given, You need to do this in two steps:

Get the id of the first record that matches the name "peter".

```
db.test.findOne({"userName":"Peter"},{"_id":1});
```

> Returns one document that satisfies the specified query criteria.  If
>   multiple documents satisfy the query, this method returns the first
>   document according to the natural order which reflects the order of
>   documents on the disk.  In capped collections, natural order is the
>   same as insertion order.

Once you have the id of the record with peter, you can retrieve the records with their id > the id of this record.

```
db.test.find({"_id":{$gte:x}});
```

Where, x is the id of the first record returned by the first query.

Comment: Yes that it! Thank you very mutch :) case can be closed!